# Latex connect words that ends with Polish Signs

Tags: unicode, cjk

I write article in Latex and I have followed problem: When I end a word with Polish sign "ąśćńęźżłó" next word is automagically connected with previous that end with those signs.

In example when I write

```
"prostą sieć internet"
```

Latex as pdf output write

```
"prostąsiećinternet".
```

My article header look as follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
```

I used CJK because I need some Japaneese signs.

Do You have any idea how to fix this?

Edit: the whole document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}

% Definition of title and author
\title{ Stack exchange example }
\author{Mazeryt
\\
ポーランド}
\maketitle


prostą sieć internet

\end{CJK*}  
\end{document}
```

But without title it is the same efect:

[image: Efect]

Comment: @David Carlisle I put my whole document with my locally printout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known bug of `CJKutf8` package. I reported the issue to Werner Lemberg months ago and the problem has been fixed: [Git commit of LaTeX-CJK](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=cjk.git;a=commit;h=cf91fd04b783e27706593d29f7ffdbb62c520026).

You can download the develop version of [`CJKutf8.sty`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=cjk.git;a=blob_plain;f=texinput/CJKutf8.sty;hb=cf91fd04b783e27706593d29f7ffdbb62c520026) from the git host before the new release of `CJK` bundle.

Or you can use this patch code after `\usepackage{CJKutf8}`:

```
\makeatletter
\endlinechar\m@ne

\def\CJK@XX#1#2{
  \ifx #2\protect
    \expandafter\CJK@XXp\expandafter#1
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname u8:\string #1\string #2\endcsname \relax
      \csname CJK@\number `#1\endcsname{`#2}
      \expandafter\CJK@ignorespaces
    \else
      \csname u8:\string #1\string #2\endcsname
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\CJK@XXp#1#2{
  \expandafter\ifx\csname u8:\string #1\string #2\endcsname \relax
    \csname CJK@\number `#1\endcsname{`#2}
    \expandafter\CJK@ignorespaces
  \else
    \csname u8:\string #1\string #2\endcsname
  \fi}

\def\CJK@XXX#1#2#3{
  \ifx #2\protect
    \expandafter\CJK@XXXp\expandafter#1#3
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname u8:\string #1\string #2\string #3\endcsname \relax
      \csname CJK@\number `#1\endcsname{`#2}{`#3}
      \expandafter\CJK@ignorespaces
    \else
      \csname u8:\string #1\string #2\string #3\endcsname
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\CJK@XXXp#1#2#3#4{
  \expandafter\ifx\csname u8:\string #1\string #2\string #4\endcsname \relax
    \csname CJK@\number `#1\endcsname{`#2}{`#4}
    \expandafter\CJK@ignorespaces
  \else
    \csname u8:\string #1\string #2\string #4\endcsname
  \fi}

\endlinechar `\^^M
\makeatother
```

Comment: Do You know how to replace CJKutf8 by CJKutf8.sty in linux env? I will be appreciated

Comment: @MazerytFreager: They are both `CJKutf8.sty`. Download the file [`texinput_CJKutf8.sty`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=cjk.git;a=blob_plain;f=texinput/CJKutf8.sty;hb=cf91fd04b783e27706593d29f7ffdbb62c520026) and rename it as `CJKutf8.sty`. Or you can use command `git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/cjk.git` to get the develop files. Use command `kpsewhich CJKutf8.sty` you can get the path of the old file. Then you can replace the old `CJKutf8.sty` with the new one.